# CDO smtp mail suddenly not sending

Tags: excel, vba, email, cdo.message

So I have this code for sending an Email from Excel VBA.
The code worked perfectly until this morning when for no apparent reason the macro worked but nothing arrived at the destination address!
Is this an SMTP relay problem and if so how do I fix it?
Or is it possible that it's a problem with "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration (I still don't know how that works! s it possible to have the schemas locally?
Or am I missing something!
Thanks in advance
Tim

Here is the macro - Only the names have been changed to protect the innocent :)

```
Sub CDO_Mail()
    Dim iMsg As Object
    Dim iConf As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim Flds As Variant

    Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
    Set Flds = iConf.Fields
    With Flds
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "Mick@mouse.com" 
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "BigSecret"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "auth.smtp.1and1.fr"

        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
        .Update
    End With
        With iMsg
        Set .Configuration = iConf
        .To = "MyEmailAddress@gm.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .From = "TheMainMan"
        .Subject = "Important message"
        .TextBody = "BODYTEXT"
        .Send

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using early binding instead. This has the added advantage of making autocompletion available. Your configuration can be setup like this:

```
Dim iConf As CDO.Configuration

Set iConf = New CDO.Configuration ' CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
With iConf.Fields
    .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
    .Item(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 465
    .Item(cdoSMTPServer) = "auth.smtp.1and1.fr"
    .Item(cdoSendUserName) = "Mick@mouse.com" 
    .Item(cdoSendPassword) = "BigSecret"
    'etc.
    .Update
End With
```

To use this you need to set an explicit reference to the CDO library: Tools > Reference > set checkmark next to Microsoft CDO.

[image: CDO reference in VBE]